# How to make my navbar sticky when i'm using div?

Tags: html, css, navbar

i'm using div, not navbar tags and it kinda confuse me. in last project i'm using the nav tags when making the navbar and using the sticky tag, and it works, but on this project my mentor want me to use div tag. i'm using the usual sticky tags, but doesn't really works. i don't understand div really well so please can someone help me out? please be kind when answering i appreciate your help for helping a newbie like me. *i'm sorry if this confusing i don't understand how to make a proper question.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
    url("Background.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-area {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-area li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-area li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-area li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.logo img {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}

.welcome-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20% 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.welcome-text h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*SECTION*/

#section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

.section1 p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css" />
  <title>Shira</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper" id="home">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="2.png" />
        <ul class="nav-area" class="sticky">
          <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="welcome-text">
        <h1>hi hshjhak</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="section1">
    <section id="section1">
      <p>AAAAAAA</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have some problem in your html : You close a `div` after you close `header` when the `div` is inside it. You close a `div` inside the `section` when the `div` is outside it

Comment: CSS doesn't care whether you try to apply this to a `nav` or a `div` element.

Comment: Css dosen’t care, but sticky DOES, if the container div has missing tags or gets closed in the wrong place, and the div does not overflow the sticky position won’t work

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this?

You must to add the class `sticky` to the "logo" div (or a common container), because you need *both* the logo and the navigation to be sticky.

**NOTE:** do not use 2 "class" attributes on a single element, like this: `<ul class="nav-area" class="sticky">`, do this: `<ul class="nav-area sticky">`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url("Background.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.nav-area {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-area li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-area li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-area li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}

.welcome-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20% 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.welcome-text h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*SECTION*/

#section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

.section1 p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">
  <title>Shira</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo sticky">
        <img src="2.png">
        <ul class="nav-area">
          <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <div class="wrapper" id="home">
      <div class="welcome-text">
        <h1>hi hshjhak</h1>
  </header>
  </div>
  <div class="section1">
    <section id="section1">
      <p>AAAAAAA</p>
  </div>
  </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```